# CSS letter cut off. How to display entire text?

Tags: css, text

I have a problem with a text in a header. I use google fonts (Pinyon Script) and one of the letters is cut off. I don't understand why... I tried with the overflow properties but it doesn't work. The problem is the header in pink on www.x4v1.com/cecile/ when the screen width is between 935 and 970 pixel. The first L of the second word is cut off and I would like to show all the text. Could you help me please ? Thanking you in advance.

On chrome :
[image: header with letter cut off]

Comment: Nothing is cut off in the address you provided

Comment: Everything looks fine to me. (using latest chrome)

Comment: I'm not seeing it either.

Comment: Always post your code in your question.

Comment: The screen width must be between 935 and 970 pixel to see the letter cut off

Comment: @X4V18 re-sized my browser to the resolutions you posted and still no problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it exactly the wrong way around. The font your using is getting out of it's inherited size (line-height, letter-spacing and so on). Therefore you should give the `h1` element a large size, and the `span` element a smaller size.

To fix this do the following:

```
<h1 id="myheader">
    C<span class="lowerfont">écile</span> 
    L<span class="lowerfont">astchenko</span>
</h1>
```

Than add the following CSS

```
#myheader {
    font-size: 6em;
}
.lowerfont {
    font-size: .75em;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it solve my problem but I just realized that I have the same problem at about 1500 pixel screen width. Could you explain me what happen and maybe how to solve it too? But thank you anyway for the help

Comment: I just check and it work but before doing this change I will try to fix that for the other resolution because I have to adapt the CSS for smaller resolution (adaptive).

Comment: This solution will work for all resolutions, because the container element (your `h1`) is bigger than the containing elements. Whereas your current code the container element is smaller than the containing elements (specifically the span elements with letters C and L)

Comment: thank you again, I will retry immediatly.

Comment: So I just retried it and it work for 950 width screen but when I'm on a resolution of 1500pixel width, the L is still cut off on the top-right corner (same problem than the previous at 950px width) and if I raise up the resolution to 1624 pixel width the letter is cut off on the bottom left corner. You can see that on www.x4v1.com/cecile/
Now, I will check sizes of elements to be sure that there isn't any element bigger than the container. big thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Cecile header]

This is what I can see, what is supposed to be missing?

Comment: This is what I want but it doesn't work if your width is between 935 and 970 pixels